# Error in creating a List of Dataview

Tags: c#, dataset, dataview

I am trying to create a list of data view which will be used later in the code as argument of a function. I am getting this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I am not sure how to initialize the list of dataview as null

```
        List<DataView> dvTablesLookup = null;
        List<DataTable> dtTablesLookup = null;

        // Creating Data View
        for (int i=0; i < datatablesLookup.Count; i++ )
        {
            dvTablesLookup[i] = new DataView(datatablesLookup[i]);
            dvTablesLookup[i].Sort = sortLookup;
            dtTablesLookup[i] = dvTablesLookup[i].ToTable();
        }
```

Comment: what is `datatablesLookup`? and you are not adding elements in list `dvTablesLookup` and `dvTablesLookup ` anywhere.

Comment: dvTablesLookup[i] = new DataView(datatablesLookup[i]); the error occur here

Comment: datatablesLookup is a count which is working fine. The error is when I try to assign values to dvTableslookup

Comment: I don't understand this "you are not adding elements in list dvTablesLookup and dvTablesLookup anywhere"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the datatablesLookup is List()

```
var datatablesLookup = new List<DataTable>();
List<DataView> dvTablesLookup = null;
List<DataTable> dtTablesLookup = null;

dvTablesLookup = datatablesLookup.Select(dt => new DataView(dt)).ToList();
dvTablesLookup.ForEach(x => x.Sort = sortLookup);
dtTablesLookup = dvTablesLookup.Select( dv => dv.ToTable()).ToList();
```

Comment: It works thanks a lot. but the query is taking even more time to lookup. I thought creating dataview would help.

Comment: Post a new question with details on the source DataTable, someone would be able to give answer for that also.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    List<DataView> dvTablesLookup = new List<DataView>();
    List<DataTable> dtTablesLookup = new List<DataTable>();

    // Creating Data View
    for (int i=0; i < datatablesLookup.Count; i++ )
    {
        DataView tempdv = new DataView(datatablesLookup[i]);
        tempdv.Sort = sortLookup;
        dvTablesLookup.Add(tempdv);                
        dtTablesLookup.Add(tempdv.ToTable());
    }
```

Comment: actually it gives the same error. My first solution was this. I thought it would work but it gives same error

Comment: try updatd answer